# Call function? Python

Tags: python, function, loops, iteration

My problem is that I want:
and then I want it to get evaluted in the calc_energy function 360 times
and then store the result so I could count the year average, I want to calculate the energy average..
Should I call the function instead of return in def_decide(v)???
Could someone help me get in on the right track?

```
def calc_v(latitud):
    for t in range(0,360):
        v=(23.5*math.sin(math.pi*(t-80)/180)+90-latitud)/90
        decide_v(v):

def decide_v(v):
    if 0<v<1:
       return(v**2)
    if v>=1:
        return(1)
    if v<=0:
        return(0)

def calc_energy(v):
    W=self.area*random(0,1)*self.sundigit*v
    return W

def sort(self,W):
    W+=100/360
```

Comment: What do you mean with loop through a function? A for loop in a function? Recursion? A function in a for loop?

Comment: @Pellegrino: please don't vandalize your own questions; that removes a lot of the usefulness of the answers people spent time crafting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a generator from `calc_v` and then use it as you would use a list of values (notice `yield` instead of `return`):

```
def calc_v(latitude):
   for t in range(0,360):
       v=(23.5*math.sin(math.pi*(t-80)/180)+90-latitude)/90
       yield v

def decide_v(v):
    if 0<v<1:
       return v**2
    elif v>=1:
       return 1
    else:
       return 0

for v in calc_v(latitude):
    print decide_v(v)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion which is a function calling itself. Below you can see the function factorial is called within itself. http://www.python-course.eu/recursive_functions.php

```
def factorial(n):
    print("factorial has been called with n = " + str(n))
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        res = n * factorial(n-1)
        print("intermediate result for ", n, " * factorial(" ,n-1, "): ",res)
        return res
```

I get the feeling that you don't really want to know how to loop a function. I think you just want to call your function in the example that you gave.

```
def calc_v(latitud):
    for t in range(0,366):
        v=(23.5*math.sin(math.pi*(t-80)/180)+90-latitud)/90
        decide_v(v) # return v

def decide_v(v):
    if 0<v<1:
        print(v**2)
    if v>=1:
        print(1)
    if v<=0:
        print(0)
```

When you use the return statement in a function then you will leave the loop and the function, so your for loop will only run through t=0 then it will break out of the function. I think you just want to call your function and give it the variable v.